# IOS,when an UIView get fully loaded

Tags: ios, objective-c, addsubview

I have an **PlayPageViewController** as `rootViewController`. The **PlayPageViewController** will display 3D models and `UIImages` in an method call **editPages()**, which will takes several seconds to wait.

I just want to add an loadingView at start and when **PlayPageViewController** gets fully loaded it will disappear.

**Here is my solution:**

1. Add an loadingView with activityIndicator.
2. When the loadingView is loaded, I will begin to implement

**but seems it didn't work**

```
    STLoadingViewController *loadingView = 
     [[STLoadingViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"STLoadingViewController" 
                                              bundle:nil];
    loadingView.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);
    [self.view insertSubview:loadingView.view atIndex:3];

    if(loadingView.isViewLoaded && loadingView.view.window)
    {
        [self.view insertSubview:self.playPageViewController.view atIndex:4];
        [self.playPageViewController setEditingPage:pageIndex];
        [loadingView.view removeFromSuperview];
    }
```

Comment: Could you add a bit more context? Where is the above code executed? Are you loading your model in the background or on the main thread? How exactly does the setup of your view controller look like? Apple suggests displaying a placeholder image and loading the content in the background to ensure your app is always responsive.

Comment: 1.The above code are executed in the ViewLoad() in rootViewController 2.I think I loaded model in main thread that why it last several seconds.3. the setup of my viewController just new image view,model view and add them into self.view,that's it. Btw,how can I loading model in backgroud

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the `ViewLoad()` method? Do you mean `viewDidLoad:`? You could setup all your views in the storyboard, including a view containing the activity indicator. Don't load the model at this point but wait until `viewDidLoad:` is called. At this point you may use [Grand Central Dispatch](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/) to start the loading of the model. It could look a bit like this:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    // You need to setup the activity indicator outlet in the storyboard
    [_activityIndicator startAnimating];
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
        // Do the expensive work on the background
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:5.0f];
        // All UI related operations must be performed on the main thread!
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{\
            // Replace the view containing the activity indicator with the view of your model.
            [_activityIndicator stopAnimating];
            NSLog(@"STOP");
        });
    });
}
```

Edit: The link seems to be down. This is probably due to the current problems with the Dev Center. You can find the documentation in the documentation pane of the Xcode Organizer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do your respective methods to call in `viewDidAppear` method when this method is called all the appearing task had been finished.